# Linux syntax errors

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I`m trying to run a bash script but for some reason this part of the output is giving me an error.

`TIER1PCT=$[ $TIER1COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]
TIER2PCT=$[ $TIER2COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]
TIER3PCT=$[ $TIER3COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]`

I am receiving this error: `:syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/ ")`

Comment: I assume variable `$TOTAL` contains no value.

Comment: The value is `TOTAL=$(cat $NEWUSERSFILE | wc -1)`

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this;

```
TOTAL=$(cat $NEWUSERSFILE | wc -l)

if [ -n "$TOTAL" ]; then
TIER1PCT=$[ $TIER1COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]
TIER2PCT=$[ $TIER2COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]
TIER3PCT=$[ $TIER3COUNT * 100 / $TOTAL ]

else 
echo  $TOTAL is null
fi
```

Comment: The output I received was `wc: invalid option -- '1' Try 'wc --help' for more information. is null "Tier 1","22","%" "Tier 2","15","%" "Tier 3","13","%"`

Comment: wc -1 option is not exist, not wc -1 , try wc -l to line count, I updated ans. maybe this could help you

Comment: This worked, it was an "l" and not a "1" the solution i`m am using it is wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is neither bash or POSIX syntax that allows:

```
$[ integer expression ]
```

Assuming you want to assign the integer result of the computations, the correct POSIX syntax would be:

```
TIER1PCT=$(( TIER1COUNT * 100 / TOTAL ))
TIER2PCT=$(( TIER2COUNT * 100 / TOTAL ))
TIER3PCT=$(( TIER3COUNT * 100 / TOTAL ))
```

Your other alternatives for integer math are with `let` or `expr`. (pay attention to the differing *whitespace* requirements for each)